# Adding strings from Unreal Engine 4 binary save file to list/array

Tags: c#, stream, binaryfiles, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to read a game's save file, which is saved in binary. Specifically I want to add all full strings separately to an array. I currently have this code:

```cs
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
    {
        while (reader.BaseStream.Position != reader.BaseStream.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadString() + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

But this, understandably, is coming up with gibberish, since I believe my while-loop advances 1 byte at a time. How can I reliably find every "actual" word in the save file? For reference, here's the information I want to extract viewed in a hex editor: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMunv.png).

Another solution that's come up is iterating over all bytes in the file and reading characters that way:

```cs
StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
bool inBuildState = false;
foreach (byte currByte in File.ReadAllBytes(path)) {
    bool isChar = currByte >= 0x20 && currByte <= 0x7F;

    if (inBuildState && !isChar) {
        Console.WriteLine(sBuilder.ToString() + "\n");
        sBuilder.Clear();
    }

    inBuildState = isChar;
    if (inBuildState) sBuilder.Append((char)currByte);
}
```

This solution works very well, actually and returns exactly the strings I need. Big thanks to @Flydog57 for this.

Comment: How are your strings encoded?  A mixture a various languages (western, middle eastern and eastern languages, say) is pretty hard to distinguish from binary data.  If your strings are all 7-bit ASCII with a null terminator then the are pretty distinguishable

Comment: That's hard for me to tell (since I don't know very much). [Here's another snippet](https://i.imgur.com/c7oYH83.png) of the file in plain text. It doesn't seem very ordered (it's generated by Unreal Engine 4).

Comment: Loop through, byte-by-byte.  If the byte is in the range 0x20-0x7f, it's likely a character.  Your program should have two states, in a string or not.  If you're not in a string and you see a likely character, transition to "in a string" and use a StringBuilder to build up a string.  As you see more likely characters, append to the StringBuilder.  When you see a "non-character" convert the StringBuilder to a string and add it to a Word list (clearing the StringBuilder for use the next time)

Comment: If you want someone to come up with a working solution, post a bunch of your binary data as a hex stream (like you have in your first image: `00 43 68 65 etc`, but as text).

Comment: The idea you had with iterating over the bytes in the file works wonderfully. I've edited my post to show the code I'm using.

Comment: Congrats, you've just written a bare-bones version of the Unix `strings` utility: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strings_(Unix)

Comment: Hey. I just wanted to update you saying that I actually found a cleaner (and hopefully faster/less resource consuming) solution. I've answered my own topic with it!

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The BinaryReader API works in such a way that it can read files you've written, or that you know conform to a particular format. In the case of ReadString(), it reads the first byte to obtain the following string's length, and if the most significant bit is 1, the length continues in the next byte, and so on. After that, it reads a certain number of bytes, according to the current encoding, and then decodes those bytes into a string.

But the file you have wasn't written by BinaryWriter, so a BinaryReader can't read it. Your file begins with `00`, so that would indicate a string length of 0.

You'll need custom code to read the bytes from this file and decode the bytes to strings. It *would* appear that all strings are preceded by `00`, if you ignore the `00 00 0x 00` sequences.

Answer (score 0):

This may be exclusive for my use-case, but here's how I ended up solving my issue; since the Unreal Engine 4-generated binary file is gibberish in a lot of places, it can't be interpreted as plain text. Therefore I must turn it into such first.
I use a regular expression pattern for that, replacing any characters that aren't part of it with spaces, resulting in one long line with lots of spaces. I then split the string on exactly those spaces and ignore all empty results (the spaces) using LINQ. This leaves me with an `IEnumerable<string>` of all real strings/words, which I convert into a `List<string>` (since that's what I need).

Here's my code:

```cs
// Regular expression containing a-z, A-Z, 0-9, -, _, and space.
Regex regex = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -_]");

// Reading the file and immediately replacing all characters not part of the regex with spaces.
string fileToPlainText = regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(filePath), " ");

// Creating a list of all items that aren't empty strings after splitting the string on spaces.
List<string> plainTextToList = fileToPlainText.Split(' ').Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToList();
```

The required `using` directives are as follows:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Comment: Since you say that this is _"hopefully faster/less resource consuming"_, you might want to have a bakeoff between using a Regex and just brute force walking through each character and doing a "is this character between 0x20 and 0x7f" test (read the same file thousands of times each way and use a stopwatch to time the results).  I'd be willing to bet $0.25 that the brute-force solution is faster.  But, if what you have is good enough, then, you know, it's good enough :)